# Can I use Mathematica in English with a Spanish keyboard?

Tags: configuration

I'm accustomed to using Mathematica in English but I've noticed that `Preferences>>Interface>>Language>>English` messes my Spanish keyboard layout. This is a bit of annoying and I'd like to know if it'd be possible to use both, the American version of the software with a non-American keyboard.

Comment: On my systems I always use the OS to switch to US keyboard layout when using Mathematica, and don't touch Mathematica's settings. Have worked well for macOS, Windows and Linux in my experience. But I write comments and code in English sooo